# bootstrap jQuery field not align and formated

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am making a form which will have 3 inputs (firstname , lastname and email). There should be an option to add additional groups of inputs.

The 3 fields and button should be a single line and properly arranged. However, they are appearing one below another. not sure where's the mistake.

This is the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Customer Query</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //group add limit
            var maxGroup = 5;
            
            //add more fields group
            $(".addMore").click(function(){
                if($('body').find('.fieldGroup').length < maxGroup){
                    var fieldHTML = '<div class="form-group fieldGroup">'+$(".fieldGroupCopy").html()+'</div>';
                    $('body').find('.fieldGroup:last').after(fieldHTML);
                }else{
                    alert('Maximum '+maxGroup+' groups are allowed.');
                }
            });
            
            //remove fields group
            $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){ 
                $(this).parents(".fieldGroup").remove();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form  method="post" action="submit.php" style="widows: 500px; margin:auto">

        <div class="form-group fieldGroup">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" name="FirstName[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name" size="10"/>
                <input type="text" name="LastName[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name" size="10"/>
                <input type="text" name="Email[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email" size="10"/>
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-success addMore"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="SUBMIT" />

    </form>

    <!-- copy of input fields group -->
    <div class="form-group fieldGroupCopy" style="display: none;">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="FirstName[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name" size="10"/>
            <input type="text" name="LastName[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name" size="10"/>
            <input type="text" name="Email[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email" size="10"/>
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> Remove</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

any help would be great

Comment: Use class form-inline in your form, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/

Comment: add `.input-group-addon {
  min-width: 120px;
}` to your css, not elegant but works. you could use `container-fluid`, `col-*` classes to make grid of your choice too

Comment: Could you show a visual of what you'd looking to achieve?

Comment: Why is this tagged Bootstrap 4 when you're using Bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem. sharing the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>L</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //group add limit
            var maxGroup = 5;
            
            //add more fields group
            $(".addMore").click(function(){
                if($('body').find('.fieldGroup').length < maxGroup){
                    var fieldHTML = '<div class="form-group fieldGroup">'+$(".fieldGroupCopy").html()+'</div>';
                    $('body').find('.fieldGroup:last').after(fieldHTML);
                }else{
                    alert('Maximum '+maxGroup+' groups are allowed.');
                }
            });
            
            //remove fields group
            $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){ 
                $(this).parents(".fieldGroup").remove();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        form {
            padding: 40px 40px 30px !important;
            background: #ebeff2;
        }

        .mt32 {
            margin-top: 32px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="mt32"> Customer Query</h2>

        <form class="form-inline mt32" action="#">
            <div class="form-group fieldGroup">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label for="FirstName">FirstName</label>&nbsp;
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="FirstName"
                        placeholder="FirstName">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <label for="LastName">LastName</label>&nbsp;
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="LastName"
                        placeholder="LastName">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <label for="email">Email</label>&nbsp;
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Your email">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-success addMore"><span
                                class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add</a>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="SUBMIT" />
        <div class="form-group fieldGroupCopy" style="display: none;">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="FirstName">FirstName</label>&nbsp;
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="FirstName"
                    placeholder="FirstName">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <label for="LastName">LastName</label>&nbsp;
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="LastName"
                    placeholder="LastName">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <label for="email">Email</label>&nbsp;
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Your email">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> Remove</a>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <br/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

It can be done using form-inline.

Refer bootstrap link : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/
[image: Inline form sample]

Comment: The question is using Bootstrap 3.3.7. Also please include the relevant parts of the code in the question, not a link with a vague image

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#input-groups
boostrap providers 3.X version form samples as well :)

Comment: If we use this approach, the submit button also get in the same line as other control which is correct . what we want is 3 text box side by side in one row. if add is clicked new row of 3 textboxes is added and so on . same goes for remove but it removes rows